# Imprimir texto posicionado em imagem

Tags: javascript, html, css, impressão

Tenho um texto posicionado no centro de uma imagem, a lógica é imprimir um certificado, e esse texto é gerado dinamicamente, isso ocorre corretamente. O problema é na hora de realizar a impressão, que o texto fica na página 2 a imagem na página 1
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<div id="DivImpressao">
<section id="AtestadoTecnico">                          
       <img id="imgAtestado" src="~/Images/Site/AtestadoTecnico.png" runat="server" class="imgAtestadoTecnico" height="685" />                           
        <div class="txtAtestadoTecnico">
                <div style="text-align: justify; font-family: Ebrima; font-size: 10pt; margin-top: 20px">
                    //texto aqui
                </div>
         </div>
      </section>
```

CSS:

```
#AtestadoTecnico {
    width: 1014px;
    height: 670px;
    position: relative;
}

.imgAtestadoTecnico {
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

.txtAtestadoTecnico {
    top: 100px;
    left: 120px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript (aqui eu passo a "DivImpressao" como parâmetro para impressão:

```
function imprimePanel(elementId) {
    var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
    var uniqueName = new Date();
    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
    var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');
    printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
}
```

Comment: Cara no teste que fiz aqui quando dou CTRL+P no Chrome não quebra a imagem em uma página e o texto na outra não... Deve ter algo a mais no seu CSS ou é esse seu script ai que está fazendo quebrar. Pq vc está dando `top=50000` na janela??

Comment: Sim, quando manda imprimir pelo Chrome, não acontece de quebrar.. Acontece quando eu clico no botão imprimir que eu criei que chama a função JavaScript que está na pergunta.. aí a quebra acontece.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver utilizando um plugin para Jquery chamado [printThis](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis) 
Muito simples de usar e ficou perfeito a página.

```
$('selector').printThis();
```